# Will my current AWS architecture scale to 20,000 visitors per day? How can I improve it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

The site I'm working on will potentially get 20,000 visitors per day. It's no guarantee, but it's supposed to be used everyday by each employee in an organisation.

In the past I've just used a single t2.micro EC2 instance with an attached EBS volume to host sites, which has always been enough because these sites don't get a lot of traffic. But with 20,000 visitors a day how could I improve my AWS architecture to scale?

The site is going to have a profile for each user, including a profile picture - so potentially 20,000 image files. Should I be writing these to an S3 bucket instead of to the EBS?

Would a t2.micro ec2 instance cope with the scale, or should I be using a t2.small, t2.medium or even t2.large?

My MySQL databases are currently on the EBS volume, but should I use RDS?

All the users are in the UK, so I'm assuming using CloudFront is overkill?

Comment: 20,000 visits a day isn't a lot of traffic.  20,000 a day is on average one request every 4.32 seconds.   You need to figure out your peak load vs. how long serving takes rather than the 20,000 a day.  For instance if it is a business there is often a peak at 9am-9:30am or at the end of the day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You're right to assume CloudFront is overkill since all your users are localized to UK.</s>

**Update:** using a CDN will take a lot of stress off your servers by caching the files rather than processing them each time a call is made.

> Look at it this way, if you get 100,000 hits a day, and 90% of those hits are cached and served by the CDN, then your server only has to process 10,000 hits a day. That could be the difference between needing a m4.xlarge versus just needing a t2.small.
>
> - [@mark-b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mark-b)

Use the Ireland region (and soon you can copy over to the UK region)

If you want to keep your database on your instance I would highly recommend a bit bigger one. As for a quick and easy solution, start up the smallest T series instance with EBS, beta test with 1000-5000 users, see how that goes. Notify the select group all their crap will disappear so don't invest a bunch o' time.

Next, get your analytics on the system and see if that will work times 4-5 more users. For SQL DB stuff you'll eventually want a M series instance I believe.

Also, you could always create a load balanced fleet. You do this in EBS by hitting Load Balanced instead of Single Instance. Create an auto scaling group and boom sauce - check that off.

As for the images, yeah I would recommend S3. Don't really want to dump the whole amount in i/o cause DB, hits, i/o, all on one instance is a lot.

Lastly, if you do plan on going to the UK region (not positive if that's been rolled out yet) I would recommend sectioning all the pieces of your application. This is really good practice to use all the resources they provide.

For a very fault tolerant system:

- EC2 fleet (m or c series) with an ELB
- S3 the images
- RDS the users
- CloudWatch the stats
- Tenecy the users with IAM groups
- Authenticate with STS or AD or whatever (kinda been in the cognito only recently)
- Store their session and authenticated crap in ElastiCache - Redis
- Keep tabs on them with Kinesis (optional)
- And let them search each other with CloudSearch (also optional)

Boss system right there!

And that's if you want to spend a bunch o' cash but have a sweet sweet system. If you want to spend next to nothing, make it serverless. A broad question asked with hundreds of combinations so this is up to interpretation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just because you don't need global distribution doesn't mean a CDN's caching wouldn't be helpful. Correct use of a CDN can greatly reduce the load on your web servers.

Comment: Even if the region could be the edge location they're pulling from?

Comment: I suppose the cached page is quicker though

Comment: If the cache server is serving the page instead of your web server, then your web server doesn't have to do any processing, thus you can have a smaller, cheaper web server. The edge server being in the same region as the web server is irrelevant to the reduction in server load that a CDN provides.

Comment: Look at it this way, if you get 100,000 hits a day, and 90% of those hits are cached and served by the CDN, then your server only has to process 10,000 hits a day. That could be the difference between needing a m4.xlarge versus just needing a t2.small.

Comment: Gotcha, that make much more sense. But what if the content on the page changes? Is there a way to knock the TTL to zero and reload the cache?
Or does it cache for whatever the TTL is, then die regardless of how many times it's hit (IE - if it caches, the cached file is hit for 10 seconds, then dies. Or is the TTL refreshed to 10 each time the page is hit?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108524/discussion-between-mark-b-and-iskore).